# Interpolate json value from ajax call in jquery

Tags: jquery, json, string-interpolation

I have an ajax call in jQuery which returns a set of values: p1, p2 ... pn.  These contain strings of a path and filename for displaying images. ie the img src value.

I want to loop through these n values ( i = 1 to n ) something like [pseudo] :

```
$("#photo_" + i).html( '<img src="' + data.p + i + '">' );
```

The selector works fine .. it's the img src I am having problems building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `data.p + i` to `data["p" + i]`

**Change**

```
$("#photo_" + i).html( '<img src="' + data.p + i + '">' );
```

**To**

```
$("#photo_" + i).html( '<img src="' + data["p" + i] + '">' );
```